# Building a dashboard with authentication

Tags: r, shiny

Using Shiny App and R, I want to build a dashboard where only the authenticated users can use. The structure of the app is:

1. Simple login page with user name box and password box, where users put user name and password
2. Dashboard page where only the users who are authenticated on login page can access

I looked through several examples such as:

https://github.com/treysp/shiny_password

https://github.com/aoles/shinypass

https://gist.github.com/withr/9001831

but here I want to address the problem when following the first example.

The problems I have:

When I put `dashboardPage()` inside `output$ui <- renderUI({ })` it did not work. So I removed `renderUI` and assigned `dashboardPage` function directly to `output$ui`, like `output$ui <- dashboardPage()`. But unfortunately it still returns this: 
`Error in tag("section", list(...)) : objet 'user_input_authenticated' introuvable`. (it's in french but it's saying that it cannot find the object).

Here are my ui.R and server.R. Other than these, you need to clone admin.R and global.R from the repository(https://github.com/treysp/shiny_password).
To create a password, please run `credentials_init()` and then `add_users("USER NAME", "PASSWORD")` with your desired user name and password. Both functions are defined in admin.R. Once you create a password, it's stored in `credentials/credentials.rds` and now you can use the app.

What I want to make is a simple dashboard with authentication. If anyone help me solve this it would be great. Also if there is any other solutions than these examples, please tell me. Thanks.

ui.R(same as the original one in the Github repository)

```
shinyUI(
  uiOutput("ui")
)
```

server.R(modified for my custom use)

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  #### UI code --------------------------------------------------------------
  output$ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "My Page"),
                             dashboardSidebar(
                               if (user_input$authenticated == FALSE) {
                                 NULL
                               } else {
                                 sidebarMenuOutput("sideBar_menu_UI")
                               }
                             ),
                             dashboardBody(
                               if (user_input$authenticated == FALSE) {
                                 ##### UI code for login page
                                 uiOutput("uiLogin")
                                 uiOutput("pass")
                               } else {
                                 #### Your app's UI code goes here!
                                 uiOutput("obs")
                                 plotOutput("distPlot")
                               }
                             ))

  #### YOUR APP'S SERVER CODE GOES HERE ----------------------------------------
  # slider input widget
  output$obs <- renderUI({
    sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:", 
                min = 1, max = 1000, value = 500)
  })

  # render histogram once slider input value exists
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    req(input$obs)
    hist(rnorm(input$obs), main = "")
  })

  output$sideBar_menu_UI <- renderMenu({
    sidebarMenu(id = "sideBar_Menu",
                menuItem("Menu 1", tabName="menu1_tab", icon = icon("calendar")),
            menuItem("Menu 2", tabName="menu2_tab", icon = icon("database"))
)
  })

  #### PASSWORD server code ---------------------------------------------------- 
  # reactive value containing user's authentication status

  # user_input <- reactiveValues(authenticated = FALSE, valid_credentials = FALSE, 
  #                              user_locked_out = FALSE, status = "")

  # authenticate user by:
  #   1. checking whether their user name and password are in the credentials 
  #       data frame and on the same row (credentials are valid)
  #   2. if credentials are valid, retrieve their lockout status from the data frame
  #   3. if user has failed login too many times and is not currently locked out, 
  #       change locked out status to TRUE in credentials DF and save DF to file
  #   4. if user is not authenticated, determine whether the user name or the password 
  #       is bad (username precedent over pw) or he is locked out. set status value for
  #       error message code below

  observeEvent(input$login_button, {
    credentials <- readRDS("credentials/credentials.rds")

    row_username <- which(credentials$user == input$user_name)
    row_password <- which(credentials$pw == digest(input$password)) # digest() makes md5 hash of password

        # if user name row and password name row are same, credentials are valid
#   and retrieve locked out status
if (length(row_username) == 1 && 
    length(row_password) >= 1 &&  # more than one user may have same pw
    (row_username %in% row_password)) {
  user_input$valid_credentials <- TRUE
  user_input$user_locked_out <- credentials$locked_out[row_username]
}

# if user is not currently locked out but has now failed login too many times:
#   1. set current lockout status to TRUE
#   2. if username is present in credentials DF, set locked out status in 
#     credentials DF to TRUE and save DF
if (input$login_button == num_fails_to_lockout & 
    user_input$user_locked_out == FALSE) {

  user_input$user_locked_out <- TRUE

  if (length(row_username) == 1) {
    credentials$locked_out[row_username] <- TRUE

    saveRDS(credentials, "credentials/credentials.rds")
  }
}

# if a user has valid credentials and is not locked out, he is authenticated      
if (user_input$valid_credentials == TRUE & user_input$user_locked_out == FALSE) {
  user_input$authenticated <- TRUE
} else {
  user_input$authenticated <- FALSE
}

# if user is not authenticated, set login status variable for error messages below
if (user_input$authenticated == FALSE) {
  if (user_input$user_locked_out == TRUE) {
    user_input$status <- "locked_out" 
  } else if (length(row_username) > 1) {
    user_input$status <- "credentials_data_error"  
  } else if (input$user_name == "" || length(row_username) == 0) {
    user_input$status <- "bad_user"
  } else if (input$password == "" || length(row_password) == 0) {
    user_input$status <- "bad_password"
  }
}
  })

  # password entry UI componenets:
  #   username and password text fields, login button
  output$uiLogin <- renderUI({
    wellPanel(
      textInput("user_name", "User Name:"),

      passwordInput("password", "Password:"),

      actionButton("login_button", "Log in")
    )
  })

  # red error message if bad credentials
  output$pass <- renderUI({
    if (user_input$status == "locked_out") {
      h5(strong(paste0("Your account is locked because of too many\n",
                       "failed login attempts. Contact administrator."), style = "color:red"), align = "center")
    } else if (user_input$status == "credentials_data_error") {    
      h5(strong("Credentials data error - contact administrator!", style = "color:red"), align = "center")
    } else if (user_input$status == "bad_user") {
      h5(strong("User name not found!", style = "color:red"), align = "center")
    } else if (user_input$status == "bad_password") {
      h5(strong("Incorrect password!", style = "color:red"), align = "center")
    } else {
      ""
    }
  })  
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A kind githubber [@skhan8](https://github.com/skhan8) just submitted a [pull request demonstrating how to use shiny_password in a shinydashboard](https://github.com/treysp/shiny_password/pull/4). It will be incorporated into the main repo soon.